# Need help working on my level 4 Ranger's Animal Companion in 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack, ranger, skills, animal-companions

So I am working on setting up my level 4 Ranger's Animal Companion in 3.5. Just got her fox. Most of it is done. My DM is having me use the Dog as the stats and stuff my fox is based off of. The only things that I can't quite figure out is is it has attack bonuses(melee, ranged, and grapple) as well as if it gets skill points and if so, how many. Any ideas? =/

I am trying to figure out a couple things.
1. Does an animal companion get skills points?
2. If they do get skill points, how do I figure that out?
3. Does an animal companion get attack bonuses for melee, ranged, or grapple?

Comment: the 'melee' and 'ranged' lines on the character sheet don't actually correspond to anything fundamental.  Melee is (usually) Str+BAB while ranged is Dex+BAB.  Your companion does have a BAB (all creatures do), as noted in the answer.

Comment: Just FYI, the internet says that there are fox stats in the Tomb of Horrors and Dragon #291, as well as for the arctic fox in Frostburn. However, these stats look at first glance to be significantly weaker than a wolf's. See http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?196249-Fox-stats.

Answer (score 9):

From [the SRD entry on Animal Companions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#theDruidsAnimalCompanion):

> *Animal Companion Basics:* Use the base statistics for a creature of the companion’s kind, but make the following changes.
>
> [...]
>
> *Bonus HD:* [...] An animal companion gains additional skill points and feats for bonus HD as normal for advancing a monster’s Hit Dice.

So, they start with the skills listed in the Monster Manual, but gain new skills as they advance.

Looking at [the entry for Dog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dog.htm):

> Base Attack/Grapple:  +0/–3
>
> Skills:   Jump +7, Listen +5, Spot +5, Survival +1*
>
> *Dogs have a +4 racial bonus on Survival checks when tracking by scent.

There is your answer for its starting skills and attack bonuses.

Looking at the rules for [advancing Hit Dice](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#tableCreatureImprovementbyType) tells us how many skill points it gains per HD:

> Animal: 2 + Int mod per HD
>
> As long as a creature has an Intelligence of at least 1, it gains a minimum of 1 skill point per Hit Die.

And [later on that page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#skills), we find out which skills can actually be advanced a rank by that one skill point:

> Treat skills listed in the base creature’s description as class skills